# Get related ID through formset

Tags: python, django

I have an inline formset which is working fine. There are a number of select boxes in the formset that lets you pick from various options in related tables.

```
QuantityFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Option, Quantity, fields=('item', 'number','area'),extra=1)
```

Item and Area are related tables.

I want to set up a button inline with the form that let's the user click through to edit these two objects.

So, for example, I want to achieve something like.

```
{% for form in quantityForm %}

  {{ form.item }}
  <a href="{% url 'editItem' form.item.id %}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
  {{ form.number }}
  {{ form.area }}
  {{ form.DELETE }}

{% endfor %}
```

However form.item.id isn't valid.

How do I get the ID for form.item (which is a select box)?

Comment: Can you use `{{ form.id }}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried {{ form.instance.item.id }}?